# Div with user-select: auto not working when nested in user-select: none

Tags: html, css

I am making a div non-selectable, and I want to re-enable selection in some of the nested divs.

```html
<div style="user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; color: red;">
  <div id="noSelection">
    Should not be able to select this text
  </div>
  <div id="selectIt" style="user-select: auto; -ms-user-select:auto; color: green;">
    Wanna select this text as normal with correct mouse cursor
  </div>
</div>
```

I expected to select the text as normal in the last div with "auto" set, but it is not working in any browsers I try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `user-select: auto;` use `user-select: text;` to make the text selectable. As the [spec states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) when using `auto`:

> if the computed value of `user-select` on the parent of this element is
>   `none`, the computed value is `none`

```html
<div style="user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; color: red;">
  <div id="noSelection">
    Should not be able to select this text
  </div>
  <div id="selectIt" style="user-select: text; -ms-user-select:auto; color: green;">
    Wanna select this text as normal with correct mouse cursor
  </div>
</div>
```